# gnuplot and octal codes 4 digit octal codes (codes larger than \777)

Tags: fonts, gnuplot, symbols, octal

As an important caveat: I do not have root on the computer where I am working. I cannot add/update anything on this computer unfortunately. This problem likely has several easy solutions (use Symbol, use UTF encoding) that will not work on this computer.

I'm trying to plot a mu within the title of a figure I generate in gnuplot, version 4.2 pl 6 in a gif terminal. There is no UTF8 encoding in this terminal/version, so {/Symbol m} notation tells me there is not symbol font, etc. I am trying to use DejaVuSans font (I can find it, so I can set GDFONTPATH for it). The character I need, lower case mu, has a hex code value of 0x03BC in this font. That translate into octal as 1674.

For other characters, I can use the notation \nnn to get the character desired. However, that notation only works up through \777. Once I need 4 octal digits for a character, gnuplot starts showing me the character encoded by the first 3 characters followed by the 4 character as a literal - ie, returning to \nnn format, and then the literal 4th digit.

Is there some way to specify an octal value greater than \777 in gnuplot?

Thanks much for any advice / suggestions / hints / commiseration

--t

Comment: You could use the `postscript` terminal, which can use the `Symbol` font since this is one of the 35 Postscript base fonts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Core_Font_Set. Then you would possibly need only ghostscript to convert it to another image format.